# Corner radius issue with UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to add a corner radius to a UIButton. It is working fine but a problem occurs when I add image to it.

It does not round its corners with images, the image is shown in full rectangle form.

Please see the image, I have used the corner radius with red color and the output is as follow:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Did you try to use set the masksToBounds: property? Fore example:

```
CALayer *layer = [myView layer];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius:8.0];
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This will work if you don't have any shadow on the button. Otherwise, just do [[button.imageView layer] setCornerRadius:8.0];

Comment: Actually Abhijeet Barge's answer is better because with maskToBounds set to YES, you cannot have shadows (ie. layer.shadowXXX )

Answer (score 9):

you use -

```
myButton.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

but make sure that your image size is exact same as button size. its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10 //this value should be half of your button's height to make a circle
yourButton.clipsToBounds = true //this clips everything outside of bounds
```