# UIButton corner radius with background Image

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to set up a custom `UIButton` which is rounded and has an image inside.
I am able to get the rounded button but after configuring the button's corner radius, the image disappears.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660265/corner-radius-issue-with-uibutton) Stack Overflow question, but after trying the solutions mentioned there, the button is still not showing the image.

A screenshot is added below:

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `super.layoutSubviews()` inside the `layoutSubviews()`

or simply remove the `layoutSubviews()` function will do the trick :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason that I have the other inits, is that I can create this button from code as well. I have tried your solution with no success. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! thank you. I have compared your code with mine, and as soon as I have removed "layoutSubviews()" it started to work properly! :) If you want to edit your answer I will accept it so other developers won't get stuck. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, will do :)

Comment: Just call `super.layoutSubviews()` inside instead of removing it.